# How to bring trisurf plot to 'bottom' and other plots to 'top'?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

In the following snippet, I try to bring the trisurf plot in the background, so the black lines of plot(x,y,':','color','k') are not hidden anymore. I tried uistack(heatmap,'bottom'), but the trisurf plot seemed unimpressed. May anybody provide a hint, how to solve this problem? Thank you and have a nice day! :)

```
close all;
figure;
hold;

x = [0.1567 0.2334 0.3098 0.3846 0.4138 0.4585 0.5183 0.1605 0.2398 0.3182 0.3952 0.4718 0.5487 0.5789 0.1629 0.2434 0.3236 0.4024 0.4814 0.5595];
x = x.';
y = [78.2114 85.3144 91.3028 95.9450 97.4787 99.4758 101.3201 88.1143 96.4935 103.4136 108.4151 112.5280 115.3430 116.3878 96.3760 105.0047 112.7581 119.3596 124.1293 128.1137];
y = y.';
z = [0.4250 0.5307 0.5916 0.6210 0.6285 0.6276 0.6251 0.4155 0.5185 0.5978 0.6350 0.6510 0.6596 0.6529 0.4024 0.5072 0.5823 0.6274 0.6415 0.6423];
z = z.';

f = @(X,Y) X;
dt = delaunayTriangulation(x,y);
P = dt.Points;
heatmap = trisurf(dt.ConnectivityList, ...
    P(:,1), P(:,2), f(P(:,1),P(:,2)), ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
    'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
    'FaceLighting', 'phong');

for i=1:10:100
     x = 0.15:0.01:0.6;
     y = i*x+80;
     plot(x,y,'--','color','k') % <- these plots should not be hidden by trisurf plot
end
```

[Example for hidden black plot lins with 'FaceAlpha' = 1.0 of trisurf plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzqQp.jpg)

[Example for visible black plot lines, because 'FaceAlpha' of trisurf plot was reduced to 0.5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl606.jpg)

Comment: What does it mean "in the background"?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I uploaded an Image, which shows the figure I want. The only Problem is, that the 'FaceAlpha' value was reduced to get this figure. As you can see, the black lines are not hidden by the trisurf plot. That's, what i meant with "in the background".

Comment: Can you show a similar example using the `peaks` function? That image you show its just a mess of lines and colors, I have no idea what you mean! is what you want to plot the edges? because you are removing them in the `trisurf` by doing `edgecolor, none`

Comment: Actually I was not able, to reproduce the problem with the peak function. Anyway I added two pictures of my real underlying Problem. As you can see by the two pictures, the black lines are hidden by the trisurf plot, as long as I don't reduce the 'FaceAlpha' value of the trisruf plot. But I don't want to do this.

Comment: I see. Is there a way you can add data from your problem? this seems to be easier to solve with the real problem

Comment: Hi there, i changed my code above accordingly :)

Comment: As a final comment, the only reason you use `f` is to create a colromap right? Can you modify your example so it does not need a function from FEX? Just add a a colormap however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you may just use plot3 function instead of plot:

```
plot3(x,y,ones(size(x)),'--','color','k') % <- these plots should not be hidden by trisurf plot
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Works perfect.